# Prove $(a_n)$ is eventually constant

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory

Let $n$ be a positive integer and define the sequence $(a_n)$ such that $a_1=n$ and $a_k$ to be the unique integer that satisfies $$0\le a_k\le k-1, \quad k\mid a_1+...+a_{k}$$
Prove that $(a_n)$ is eventually constant.

Here is my approach

Take $n=1$, Using strong induction you can easily prove that $a_k=1 \forall k\ge  1$. For $n=2$ gathering some values of $(a_n)$ you can prove using strong induction that the sequence is eventually constant. But how can I prove it to any $n$

Comment: Let $s_k=a_1+\cdots +a_k$.  Note that we can write $s_k=ck$, by assumption and using $a_n=c$ for all $n>k$ would work, except that it might violate the inequality (there's no reason $c$ must be $≤k-1$). But if it ever happens that $c$ is $≤k-1$, then the sequence is constant after that.  Now just think about how quickly $s_k$ can grow.

Comment: What does eventualy constant means?

Comment: For sufficiently large n, $a_{n+1}=a_n$.@Aqua

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $s_k=a_1+\cdots+a_k$.  Since $k\,|\,s_k$ by assumption we can also define the natural number $c_k=\frac {s_k}k$.

The key remark is that, if we ignore the inequality, we could always just use $c_k$ past $s_k$.  Indeed, $j>k$ would then give us $$s_j=kc_k+(j-k)c_k=jc_k\implies j\,|\,s_j$$

The only problem is that $c_k$ might be $>k-1$.  But that can't happen forever.  Indeed, $$s_k≤n+\sum_{i=2}^k (i-1)=n+\frac {k(k-1)}2$$

If $c_k≥k$ we'd have $s_k≥k^2$ but $k^2>n+ \frac {k(k-1)}2$ for large $k$ so we are done.